# How to remove node in trained Tensorflow graph

Tags: python, scala, tensorflow

I am using tensroflow 1.15.0

I am working federated-learning with tensorflow. Therefore, there are some transferation nodes (which are customized nodes defined by PyFunc) in my graph. I would like to use serving in other language, such as go or scala. So I hope to save the model using savedModel. However, the PyFunc node are not possible to load in scala. So how can I remove some nodes after I trained this model and save it as a Normal model.

By the way, it is hard to not use customized node since there is no transfer ops in tensorflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Let's say, I have a trained tf model. I have used some PyFunc nodes in training process which are not neccessary in the serving process. I want to remove these nodes after the model is trained. So how to achieve it?